# loop error while using sprintf

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying a simple thing in c code:

```
const char *files[4];
char buffer[50];
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
sprintf(buffer,"test%i%s", i, ".txt");
files[i] = buffer;
}
```

output of files:

```
test4.txt
test4.txt
test4.txt
test4.txt
test4.txt
```

what I really wanted to achieve:

```
test0.txt
test1.txt
test2.txt
test3.txt
test4.txt
```

Can any anyone tell me whats wrong? (files has to be const char*)

Comment: buffer is a pointer and you assign/modify the same pointer on each iteration. instead of files[i] = buffer you should use strdup().

Comment: Can you show me how? The anwsers at the bottom don't consider that I need the files to be const char*

Comment: After `sprintf` replace `files[i] = buffer;` with `files[i] = strdup(buffer);`. Do not forget that memory allocated with `strdup()` must be deallocated with `free()`.

Comment: hmm doesn't work..the .exe crashes now.

Comment: crashes...where? code you posted, modfied, won't crash...

Comment: I'm confused now..I changed it to files[i] = strdup(buffer); and free(buffer); it keeps crashing. So I tried to change the second line to char* buffer, now it works. But I got the waring it may be used uninitialized, to avoid that I changed it to char* buffer = NULL then running failed with "warning: Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function."

Comment: You have to free() AFTER you used, before program finishes - not inside loop (in a dummy example you may even skip). BTW you do not have to free(buffer) because it's not allocated with malloc(), you have to free files[0], files[1] and so on (because strdup() allocates new memory).

Answer (score 5):

The variable `buffer` has the same address throughout the execution of the program.

Hence `files[0]`, `files[1]`, `files[2]` and `files[3]` will all point the same address.

In the last iteration of the loop you are attempting to set `files[4]`, which yields undefined behavior.

---

For what you're trying to achieve, you could do something like:

```
int i;
char files[5][50];
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    sprintf(files[i],"test%d.txt",i);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are copying all strings into the same buffer, so ultimately all `files` elements point to this same string. Use `strdup`, `malloc`, or a fixed string buffer to store the names in.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
char files[5][10];
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    sprintf( files[i], "test%i%s", i, ".txt" );
}
```

As for your code then there is a memory overflow because you defined array files as having 4 elements but used 5 elements. And you allways assigned the same address of variable buffer to elements of the array.